# How to get account load information on Linux shared host?

Tags: php, linux, load, shared-hosting

I have developed a PHP program that gives me the current load when executing a function. For this I use `sys_getloadavg()`, but also a script to be able to output the load as a percentage.

This program works perfectly, but only when used on a dedicated server or any other server where the hardware resources are not shared. This script also works on shared hosting, but the load status always refers to the entire server and not to the respective account. In my cPanel CP, however, I see information about the load that relates to my account.

Therefore the question arises whether it is possible to obtain the load information from my account specifically?

Additional information: Using https://phpsysinfo.github.io/phpsysinfo/ I see at least the CPU load on each CPU core, but I don't assume that 1 core is reserved for 1 account?

Comment: `I don't assume that 1 core is reserved for 1 account`...I don't know a lot about shared hosting architecture, but I'd be pretty surprised if that was the case. It sounds like a very inefficient way to share resources (because there would be huge amounts of redundancy when a site was idle), and would also severely constrain the number of accounts which could be hosted on one server.

Comment: That's why I don't think it's going to be handled that way.

Comment: Anyway, the fact is that cPanel and probably every other CP can at least read the load based on the CPU load. However, cPanel can only use what Linux provides for this. So there has to be something in Linux to dump the load, if only the CPU load.

Comment: Indeed there possibly is. I'm not the right person to answer that though, I only saw your post due to the PHP tag. Maybe someone else will be able to help.